# Pass a variable to a parent form in twig

Tags: forms, symfony, twig

I need to pass a variable to a parent form in twig:

```
{# This block is called for the children and the parent #}
{% block form_rows %}
    {% for child in form %}
        {% if child.vars.foo == 'bar' %}
            {% set form.vars = form.vars|merge({'key': 'value'}) %}
        {% endif %}

        {# Parent check children key var #}
        {% if child.vars.key %}
            {# do something #}
        {% endif %}

        {# Will call children form_rows block recursively #}
        {{ form_row(child) }}
    {% endfor %}
{% endblock form_rows %}
```

This of course don't work because you cannot set a variable like this and `form` is an object not an array.
I couldn't find any solution until now.

Comment: IMHO this kind of logic should not be performend in the template. MVC pattern tells us to do this stuff in php.

Comment: I knew that I would have that comment but it is not what I want because I'm sure you are right. I just want to know if there is a way to do it, and how.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, the whole thing is a bad idea, but it should be possible since Twig v1.2 using the `attribute` function. For that you need a setter Method in you form object, eg:

```
class YourFormClass {
  public $vars;

  /* your class code comes here */

  public function setVars($newVars) {
    $this->vars = $newVars;
  }
}
```

Assuming that the twig `form` variable is an instance of `YourFormClass` you can now use the `attribute` function like this:

```
{% set newVal = form.vars|merge({'key': 'value'}) %}
{{ attribute(form, 'setVars', [newVal]) }}
{{ dump(form.vars) }}
```

Comment: This is not working for me... `Method "setVars" for object "Symfony\Component\Form\FormView" does not exist`. This is because form is an instance of `FormView` not an instance of `YourFormClass`.

Comment: Of course. ´YourFormClass´ was just for illustration. In your case the ´setVars´ method should be a member of ´FormView´, or if that is not possible you could extend the class.